# Is this behavior normal for lock screen and Phone app for android 4.1.2?

Tags: lock-screens

Is this the normal behavior for the LOCK SCREEN?

Scenario

When on Phone app, after disconnecting the call.

1. Tap on Call button again
2. Mean while Screen times out, and device shows lock screen (for fraction of seconds)
3. But, skips the lock screen and shows the phone app again.

Basically it is like skipping the lock screen without passcode.

Device: Samsung Galaxy Note2, 4.1.2 Jellybean, with the latest update of 'XXDMC3'.
Observed this scenario before and after this particular update is installed.

Edit:

My intention here is to know why some times the default 'Phone' app bypasses the LOCK SCreen.  In the scenario I mentioned, when I again tap on the call button, The screen timeout should be calculated from that instance of time. But that doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your ROM, there might be two settings for screen lock:

- user turns of screen explicitly (default: lock immediately)
- screen turns off by timeout (default: lock after 5 seconds if not switched on again by user before that)

You might wish to check with your device. It's usually found in *Settings→Display*. Not that this is not separately configurable on all devices.

Comment: What I wanted to know is, why sometimes the default 'Phone' app bypasses the lock screen.

Comment: It has to e.g. on incoming calls. If you have a "more complicated" lock, you otherwise might become unable to pick up an incoming call before the caller hangs up. But the case you described (*automatic* screen timeout as opposed to *manually triggered*) it's rather the second item in my answer's list. And it would not only affect the dialer app, but should be the same with other apps as well.

Comment: Its automatic screen timeout. But as of I know the time needs to be calculated when there are no interactions to the device from the user. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: No correction needed, you are right. In the described case I guess the "tap" happened just to overlap with the timeout -- I have no other explanation for this. And obviously, simply talking on the phone (without any screen interactions) seems not to count as "interacting with the device" in *this* context.